# d3 linear color scale output is wrong

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following function:

```
function getColor(value){
    //value from 0 to 1
    var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range(colorbrewer.Greys[9]);

    console.log(value + " = > " + color(value));

    return color(value);
}
```

This uses the [colorbrewer.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/lib/colorbrewer) from D3.

However, the values returned are off.

For example I get:

`1 = > #f0f0f0` and `0 = > #ffffff` which happen to be the first and second in the scale:

`["#ffffff","#f0f0f0","#d9d9d9","#bdbdbd","#969696","#737373","#525252","#252525","#000000"]`

How can I make it interpolate so that it calculates the right color based on a value between 0 and 1? I also tried the ordinal scale, but that didn't help much either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do is use [quantize scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantize-scales)

> Quantize scales are a variant of linear scales with a discrete rather than continuous range. The input domain is still continuous, and divided into uniform segments based on the number of values in (the cardinality of) the output range.

Consider this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zhEypYosCgxnIdrxrdhi?p=preview):

where the key is:

```
function getColor(value){
    //value from 0 to 1
    var color = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range(colorbrewer.Greys[9]);

    console.log(value + " = > " + color(value));

    return color(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear):

> The array must contain two or more values, to match the cardinality of the input domain, otherwise the longer of the two is truncated to match the other.

So you could either take just the first and last value of the colorbrewer array, or give more values for the input domain that correspond to the respective output.

Comment: Hmmm that's what I kind of figured. How do you construct such an interval, or even better, is there a way to create a new hex color code based on a float value between 0 and 1?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but you could simply divide 1 by the number of values to get your step and then have a loop that adds the interval at each iteration to get the domain.

Comment: But that makes an ordinal scale right? Suppose you have 2 colors: black and white and 2 values 0 and 1. You then either pick black or what when querying the scale. I would like that it for example returns grey on 0.5

Comment: No, it's different from an ordinal scale in that it will still interpolate for input values that are not exactly in the domain.